# Magento: cURL extension has to be loaded

Tags: zend-framework, magento, curl, ubuntu-12.04, magento-1.4

I want to run a copy of one of our Magento installations on my local machine. I've copied the code, recreated the database on my local machine, configured apache, and now try to run it. I get the following message:

> There has been an error processing your request
>
> cURL extension has to be loaded to use this Zend_Http_Client adapter.

I've searched for solutions on the internet, but couldn't find a solution.

Curl was not installed, so I did this: `apt-get install php5-curl`

I opened /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini and looked for php_curl.dll, which was not mentioned in it. So I added the following line: `extension=php_curl.dll`. After restarting apache nothing changed. Shouldn't that DLL be in there? I've tried to search for the string inside /etc/php5 and /etc using grep, but no results.

Now I wonder what to do to get magento working. I don't care about Curl, this installation is meant to test, try out, and it doesn't need all options installed. Best would be if this worked, but it's not a necessity for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed php_curl.dll to php_curl.so and that seems to solve the problem.

Comment: `.dll` is for window base system, while `.so` is linux base system